# pdftotext is not getting installed in windows

Tags: python-3.x, data-extraction, pdftotext

I am trying to extract data from an invoice. I found invoice2data will do that job. I have pip installed invoice2data.

```
from invoice2data import extract_data
```

This is getting imported.

```
result = extract_data('sample.pdf')
```

When I run the above line it is showing that

```
OSError: pdftotext not installed. Can be downloaded from https://poppler.freedesktop.org/
```

When I try pip installing pdftotext it was showing virtual c++ 14.0 is required.I installed it using build tools. Again it was showing the same error. So I downloaded the files from https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/ and pasted the extracted files in my anaconda/Lib/sitepackages directory. Now when I try to pip install pdftotext it is showing `Requirement already satisfied: pdftotext in c:\users\vicky\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.1.2)` Now, when I try to extract data from the pdf it is again showing the same error that pdftotext is not installed. How can I overcome this error or is there any other package that will satisfy my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand the error message to mean that you are not missing the libraries (they are the ones giving the error), but that the libraries need to interface with a binary that is separately installed. Have you tried the link?

Comment: @oligofren. Which link should I try?

Comment: The link from the error message: https://poppler.freedesktop.org. it contains some software I believe will interface with the library. On the page it describes how other APIs interface with it.

Answer (score 1):

Install  poppler-utils before pdftotext

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

the dep are here
https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/
just have a look and instal them before pip install pdf2text

Answer (score -1):

some simple steps to do, which worked for me...

**1. download and install Visual Studio with C++ Build Tools, as Microsoft Visual C++ is required.**
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

**2. Download the latest binaries of Popplers for Windows**
https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/index.html

**3. Extract and copy the 'poppler' folder which is inside the folder 'include'**

[image]

**4. Past this 'poppler' folder inside the 'Anaconda3/include/' folder**

[image]

**5. Then run '`pip install pdftotext`'**

YOU ARE DONE!!!