# pip install pdftotext python without Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, pdftotext, poppler

is there a way to pip install pdftotext without Anaconda?

I´ve managed to open pdftotext with commandline. I´ve installed poppler and add it to path, I´ve also installed the code extentions C++ Visual Studio.

but I still get error when I try to  use pip install pdftotext.
Have someone manage to install it without anaconda?
I´m running Windows 10.

why does it complain about pkg-config if it´s in the poppler installation?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCx13.png

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: oh sorry Windows 10, I ill edit my Question.

Comment: docs say current that only tested (works) on conda, have you try this https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext#windows ?

Comment: I was afraid of this, I whan to avoid Anaconda, would it be possible to write a script with Popen to actually run the pdftotext from the commanline first and then extract the file from path?

Comment: perhaps, this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392015/installing-poppler-for-pdf-text-extraction

Comment: Thank you, I´´ve missed that, been searching for a solution the whole day.

Comment: See this thread, it may help you solve https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619402/9549067

Answer (score 0):

See this thread, it may help you solve.
I have detailed the steps in that thread. It seems you missed the Poppler package which is the main dependency. Since installing the C++ packages is not enough to solve the issue on the Windows platform.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619402/9549067